# Why different salaats have different number of rakaats?

Tags: salat, sunnah

What is the motivation behind having different numbers for different prayers? Is there any significance attached to it, as in one prayer is different than others? Is this Allah's word (I doubt for I don't think its mentioned in Quran) or Sunnah? What are some credible/authoritative sources to know more about this?

Comment: See: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7339/how-many-rakat-in-salat-fard-salat-only

Comment: Thanks for the link. Although it is detailed, it still didn't answer my question  - where the differences came from.

Answer (score 4):

Prayer is the direct command of Allah conveyed to the Prophet (without intermediaries Jibril) at Isra 'Mi'raj. As for the number of rakaat in the sholah is delivered Prophet Muhammad and taught by the Prophet SAW

Rasulullah said:

> "Pray ye as ye see me pray"

So we just have to listen and obey

Wallaahu a'lam

Answer (score 0):

In coran there it is not precised the number of rakaaat but it's detailed in sunna and how profet Mohammed did every prayer .
the secret behind number of rak3at in every prayer only god know the reason behind it

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are not to be used for extended discussion or debate; they should be limited to only those which are directly relevant to the post itself. (courtesy ping @Dirt)