# How many salat/prayer ordered by Allah (SWT) in a single day?

Tags: salat

Hello brothers & sisters,

I am from India, belief in single & only Allah (SWT).

I want to know how many salat odered by Allah in a whole single day.

And how many sunnat, ferz, navafil salats in each of salat.

I am confused due to many books & authors answer & there belief differently about total salat for a day and how many salat in each?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe useful http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7339/how-many-rakat-in-salat-fard-salat-only?noredirect=1&lq=1 and http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/928/does-the-idea-of-prayer-5-times-a-day-come-from-the-quran ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total 5 Salah in a day.

1. A salah that do before 5am is called **Fajar** having 2sunnat and 2farz.
2. A salah on 1.30pm is called **Zohar** having 4sunnat, 4farz, 2sunnat and 2nafeel.
3. A salah on 4.30-5.15pm (approx) may different with countries is called **Asar**. Having 4sunnat and 4farz.
4. A salah on 7:00-7:30pm is called **Maghrib** having 3farz, 2sunnat and 2nafeel.
5. A salah on 8:30-9:00pm is called **Isha**  having 4sunnat, 4-farz, 2sunnat, 2nafeel, 3witar-wajib and 2 nafeel.

Comment: I think the times you posted are irrelevant, as the prayer times depend on where you are!